# Call @IBInspectable set in @IBDesignable after layer is updated by constraints

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I want to make an @IBInspectable for UIView that makes UIView as a circle:

```
@IBInspectable var circleBorder: Bool {
    set {
       layer.cornerRadius = layer.frame.size.width / 2
    }
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius > 0 ? true : false
    }
}
```

The problem is that my @IBInspectable is called before constraints modifies its value and a wrong cornerRadius is being set. 
Is it possible to get the layer size after constraints here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is, but there's a better way - expose `cornerRadius`.

This way the developer can do things in their own sequence. Exposing things in a `Bool` means that in IB a developer needs to (1) create the view, (2) add the constraints, (3) update the frames, and *then* (4) set the `Bool`. (Also, in Xcode 8, I'm guessing if you change the device in IB - even after getting the sequence correct - things may not properly update.

Unless you have a specific reason - which I can't come up with - to make this a `Bool`, this is not only harmless, it is more customizable.

The code:

```
@IBInspectable public var cornerRadius:CGFloat {
    get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
    }
    set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've been using this. But I faced the problem that if UIView size is dynamic and the constraints changes it the cornerRadius must change too.

Comment: I see what you are saying. You may not be able to accomplish what you want 100%. :-( In my eyes, this gets down to IB being a *design-time* tool and "a perfect circle" (`frame.size.width/2`) being a *runtime* calculation. I had the same kind of thing happen - I wanted to move a set of controls from the bottom to the right, depending on the orientation. IB couldn't handle it, because iPads have the same size class no matter the orientation. I ended up ditching IB entirely, as it's easily done in code!